# maxTableColumnSize in .ipsproject-File

Tags: faktor-ips

I need to store a String of at least 2000 chars in the database, but i get the following validation message in Faktor-IPS:

Spalten-Size erreicht das Limit [1..255]

I found the PersistenceOptions in the .ipsproject-File and the attribute maxTableColumnSize - which is set to 255. If I change this value to 2000, all seems fine. Are there other effects if this value is changed or is this attribute only used for the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'maxTableColumnSize' is only used for this validation and should be set according to your database implementation. Typical values can be found here: https://blog.faktorzehn.de/2021/06/faktor-ips-persistenz-optionen/?lang=en